Caculating Prices of Goods
I have looked on the forum and I am wondering if there is a better way to go this. I would like to set a value for the total cost of something and then calculate the price and output it into my document. I have adapted an answer from the forums but it appears that the package does not respect the font and uses it's own font.
I am loading calibra locally copied form Windows
Appreciate any pointers - thank you :)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=fonts/,
    BoldItalicFont =calibriz.ttf,
    BoldFont       =calibrib.ttf,
    ItalicFont     =calibrii.ttf]{calibri.ttf}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/fpu = true,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    precision=2,
    fixed,
    fixed zerofill,
    1000 sep={,}
}
\newcommand{\TotalCost}{87500}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{\TotalCost*1.1}
\$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
\end{document}


Have look here, at floating points: https://texdoc.org/serve/interface3/0#page267 . Also check https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/expl3/info

Here is a simple example.
The \demo macro shows you some principles, while the \row macro simplifies creating table-rows with these calculations.

Unfortunately format specifiers for \fp_ are still to be defined, while you can convert the calculated result to a tokenlist via \fp_to_tl:N and do some extraction wrt precision (2 digits etc.; see the String section in https://texdoc.org/serve/interface3). (New: see P.S.)

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \fp_new:N   \l_demo_price_fp
    \fp_new:N   \l_row_pr_fp
    \fp_new:N   \l_row_fc_fp

    \newcommand\demo[0]{
        \fp_set:Nn  \l_demo_price_fp {1000 }
        \fp_set:Nn  \l_demo_price_fp { 1.1234567 * \l_demo_price_fp }
        \fp_use:N   \l_demo_price_fp
    }
    
    \newcommand\mult[2]{
        \fp_set:Nn  \l_row_pr_fp { #1 }
        \fp_set:Nn  \l_row_fc_fp { #2 }
        \fp_set:Nn  \l_row_pr_fp { \l_row_pr_fp * \l_row_fc_fp }
        \fp_use:N   \l_row_pr_fp    
    }
    
    \newcommand\row[2]{#1&#2&\mult{#1}{#2}\\}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \demo
  \bigskip
  
  \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
        Price   & Factor    & TotalCost\\
    \midrule
        \row{1000}{1.1}
        \row{567.73}{1.19}
        \row{300}{33}
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}

P.S.: Introducing decimals
According to Truncating floating point numbers ... and How to set the precision in numbers using the siunitx package solves the precision problem, absorbed by macro \frmt. Note that in this version  \frmt has to be appliead inside \mult.

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \fp_new:N   \l_demo_price_fp
    \fp_new:N   \l_row_pr_fp
    \fp_new:N   \l_row_fc_fp


    \newcommand\demo[0]{
        \fp_set:Nn  \l_demo_price_fp {1000 }
        \fp_set:Nn  \l_demo_price_fp { 1.1234567 * \l_demo_price_fp }
        \fp_use:N   \l_demo_price_fp
    }
    
    % ~~~ format with 2 decimals ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \newcommand\frmt[1]{\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{#1}}

    \newcommand\mult[2]{
        \fp_set:Nn      \l_row_pr_fp { #1 }
        \fp_set:Nn      \l_row_fc_fp { #2 }
        \fp_set:Nn      \l_row_pr_fp { \l_row_pr_fp * \l_row_fc_fp } % calc
        \frmt{\fp_use:N \l_row_pr_fp}   % format
    }
    
    \newcommand\row[2]{\frmt{#1}&\frmt{#2}&\mult{#1}{#2}\\}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
    \parindent0pt

  \demo
  \bigskip
  
  \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
        Price   & Factor    & TotalCost\\
    \midrule
        \row{1000}{1.1}
        \row{567.73}{1.19}
        \row{300}{33}
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}


Thanks for the response. I have some reading to do in order to understand how this working. Appreciate it but it's a little over my head at this moment

You're welcome. // Yes, it's a lot ... at least it looks like at first glance. I suggest you follow the links from my comment first (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/727006/caculating-prices-of-goods/727008?noredirect=1#comment1809737_727006) , esp. from the tag info. // In a nutshell the Latex3-team turned sometimes adventurous macro expansion into a quite uniform and reliable expl3 syntax, which is quite repetitive.
